# Angular 2 / 4 - How to know if API is Online?

Tags: api, angular, express, real-time

I have a NodeJS Express API with this route http://localhost:4040/online

returning :

```
{
  "status": "true"
}
```

if my API is online.

In my Angular 2 (4) application, I want to know in real time if my API is Online true or Online False.

I try many things but I cant get the status in real time, I need do call some service method. Is there a way to do that ?

## UPDATE

This is my new code https://gist.github.com/duard/05283f1625c807f50ebc5cfb289e7ae4

It works, but I see in my console it trying to check the URL every 5 seconds ... I'm not happy yet :-(
[image]

## OLD CODE

**My Application**

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
  data: any[];

  constructor(private http: Http, private apiService: ApiService) {
    this.apiService.getData().subscribe(
      data => {
      this.data = data;
    }, 
    error => { 
      this.data = [{status: "false"}] ;
    });
  }
}
```

**My service**

```
export class ApiService {

  private url: string = `http://localhost:4040/online`;

  private data: any[];
  private observable: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getData() {
    console.log('getData called');
    if (this.data) {
      console.log('data already available');
      // if `data` is available just return it as `Observable`
      console.log(' =>  ' + ' pegou cache');
      return Observable.of(this.data);
    } else if (this.observable) {
      console.log('request pending');
      // if `this.observable` is set then the request is in progress
      // return the `Observable` for the ongoing request
      return this.observable;
    } else {
      console.log('send new request');
      let headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      // create the request, store the `Observable` for subsequent subscribers
      this.observable = this.http.get(this.url, {
        headers: headers
      })
        .map(response => {
          console.log('response arrived');
          // when the cached data is available we don't need the `Observable` reference anymore
          this.observable = null;

          if (response.status == 400) {
            return "FAILURE";
          } else if (response.status == 200) {
            this.data = response.json();
            return this.data;
          }
          // make it shared so more than one subscriber can get the result
        })
        .share();
      return this.observable;
    }
  }
}
```

**My Template**

```
<h1>
  {{title}}
</h1>
<hr>
<h3>capitol</h3>
{{ capitol | json}}
<h3>data</h3>
{{ data | json}}
{{ (data | async) | json}}
<hr>
```

If I use this ASYNC I get errors.

Comment: why async there?

Comment: You insist on being able to know the status "in real time", but you have an incredibly complex piece of code, where the complexity only allows you to return a cached, thus old and obsolete status, which is thus not realtime at all. Why don't you just send a request every time the status is requested? That would be much more real-time, and would make the code much simpler.

Comment: Only a test i did ... In this way I need to refresh my app everytime to get API Online TRUE or FALSE ( F5 or Ctrl+shift+R)

Comment: I'm doing this to put some image RED when my API is Offline and GREEN when it is Online ... and I want it in real time :-/

Comment: I try another code and now it works but in my console I see it trying to check my URL every 5 seconds ... I'm not happy yet https://gist.github.com/duard/05283f1625c807f50ebc5cfb289e7ae4 :-/

Comment: What does "I'm not happy yet" mean? What do you want instead?

Comment: I want some thing more Angular, like when I see record been inserted in my table ... I dont need to specify this 5 seconds, they just apear on my template.

ps. sorry my bad english.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141254/discussion-between-duardbr-and-jb-nizet).